# Replace CSV headers in file

Tags: powershell

I'm using `Set-Content` to replace the headers in a CSV file, it replaces the headers but it also clears out all the rows of data below the headers.

Is there a way to code it so I won't loose the data after the headers are replaced?

```
$Location = "$home\performance2.csv"

$PreformHeaderRow1 =@()
$PreformHeaderRow2 =@{}

$PreformHeaderRow1 = (Get-Content $Location | Select-Object
-First 1).Split(",")
$PreformHeaderRow1 | % {
$PreformHeaderRow2.Add($_ -replace '"',"" ) 
}

$NewHeaders =@()  
ForEach($objectA in $HeaderLookup.Keys){
     ForEach($objectB in $PreformHeaderRow2.Keys){
         if($objectA -eq $objectB){
           $NewHeaders+= $HeaderLookup[$objectA]
         }
     }
 }

[string]$a = $NULL
$a = $NewHeaders -join ""","""
$a | Set-Content -First 1 $Location
```

Comment: Can you try this - 
`Import-Csv -Path $home\performance2.csv -Header col1,col2,col3 | select -Skip 1 | Export-Csv $home\Newperformance2.csv -NoTypeInformation`.

If your aim is to only replace the headers in your `csv` file.

Comment: @VivekKumar your code removes the headers, it doesn't replace them with new ones like OP requires.

Comment: I think that's what the requirement was, **won't loose the data after the headers are replaced**. But your solution also seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Set-Content` doesn't have a `-First` param like `Get-Content`, it just overwrites the file with the contents of the `Value` param, as all you were passing it was the first row that's all the file was updated with.

You can select the first line by index `$content[0]`, replace only its value `$content[0] = $NewHeaders -join '","'` before using `Set-Content`:

```
$Location = "$home\performance2.csv"

$PreformHeaderRow1 =@()
$PreformHeaderRow2 =@{}

$content = Get-Content $Location

$PreformHeaderRow1 = $content[0].Split(",")
$PreformHeaderRow1 | % {
    $PreformHeaderRow2.Add($_ -replace '"',"" ) 
}

$NewHeaders =@()  
ForEach($objectA in $HeaderLookup.Keys){
     ForEach($objectB in $PreformHeaderRow2.Keys){
         if($objectA -eq $objectB){
           $NewHeaders+= $HeaderLookup[$objectA]
         }
     }
 }

$content[0] = $NewHeaders -join '","'
$content | Set-Content $Location
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a line with fixed content above it, you could do the following:

```
$output = "C:\temp\t.csv"
$Content = Get-Content $output
$add_above_all_else = 'header1;header2;header3;header4;header5'
Set-Content $output -value $add_above_all_else,$content
```

This will leave all your rows as they are, but just add a line above them with your fixed headers.